# Prevent specific parts of buffer from being editable

Tags: buffers, buffer-modified

I wonder if it is possible to prevent specific parts of a buffer from being editable. For example, when I have outlined my document in an org-mode file, 
I would like to prevent any accidental changes to the headlines, and only being able to edit the contents:

```
* Headline 1: not editable

Content under Headline 1 is editable.

* Headline 2: not editable

Content under Headline is editable.

** Subheadline 1 under Headline 2: not editable

Content under Subheadline 1 is editable
```

Or if I have code block in an org-file, I would like to prevent changes to the code block commands:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp                       <- not editable
(defun fun (a b)                             <- editable
  (+ a b)                                    <- editable
#+end_src                                    <- not editable
```

**EDIT:** I would prefer a solution where the non-editable parts can still move up or down the y-axis in the buffer to ensure that content in between non-editable parts can be expanded:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp              <- not editable, but can move up or down
(defun fun (a b)                    <- editable
  (+ a b)                           <- editable
)                                   <- editable
#+end_src                           <- not editable, but can move up or down
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just put text-property `read-only` on those bits of text.

For example, to make a zone of text from position `START` to position `END` read-only, do this:

```el
(put-text-property start end 'read-only t)
```

Comment: So, for example, I would have to find the beginning and end positions of all occurrences of `org-mode` headlines and then apply said function to all of them?

Comment: Ok, the issue seems to be that this locks the text in an absolute position on the y-axis. In the above examples this maybe detrimental, if one wants to insert more text within area encompassed by the read-only parts.

Comment: If you want to insert text then the place where you want to insert it cannot be read-only. Rather, it could be read-only, and your code that inserts there could temporarily inhibit the read-only aspect: e.g., bind variable `inhibit-read-only` to non-`nil`. (But the question is not clear wrt wanting the text to be read-only vs wanting to insert there.)